# add album art to WMA file

Tags: windows, winapi, wmp, albumart

I'm using WMP engine to convert audio to WMA format, but I didn't see any API that I can put a alubm art to WMA file. is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/articles/100730.aspx) a try.

You can do it by using `MediaCatalog`,which gives you an API to do this sort of thing, as explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TagLib Sharp](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp). I have once used this to read album art. I am sure you can useit write it back too.